# Is there some limit result with conditional expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, probability-limit-theorems

Let $Y$ be a random variable and $\mathcal F_n$ be an increasing sequence of sigma algebras.

Do we have some limiting result for $E[Y \mid \mathcal F_n]$?

For example, if $$\mathcal F_\infty = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \mathcal F_n = \cap_{n=1}^\infty \cup_{m\ge n} \mathcal F_m$$

is a sigma algebra, can we say that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} E[Y \mid \mathcal F_n] = E[Y \mid \mathcal F_\infty]$$?

Comment: You should look at the Lévy's zero-one law.

Comment: @Ahriman Well thank you very much! You can make that an answer if you'd like :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional expectation stable by passing into the limit in $L^{1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926886/conditional-expectation-stable-by-passing-into-the-limit-in-l1)

Comment: It does, thank you!